# Converting nested JSON into CSV by adding the nested objects to s single column in Apache Nifi

Tags: json, csv, apache-nifi, avro

I have a nested object JSON structure as given below;

```
{
"Bikes":[
{
"Name":"KTM",
"Model":"2017",
"Colour":"Yellow"
}
{
"Name":"Yamaha",
"Model":"2020",
"Colour":"Black"
}
],
"Cars":[
{
"Name":"BMW",
"Model":"2017",
"Colour":"Yellow"
}
{
"Name":"Audi",
"Model":"2020",
"Colour":"Black"
}
]
```

My output CSV should look this;

```
Bikes (Column 1)
{
"Name":"KTM",
"Model":"2017",
"Colour":"Yellow"
}
{
"Name":"Yamaha",
"Model":"2020",
"Colour":"Black"
}
Cars (Columns 2)
{
"Name":"BMW",
"Model":"2017",
"Colour":"Yellow"
}
{
"Name":"Audi",
"Model":"2020",
"Colour":"Black"
}
'''
I need to store the entire object Bikes in a single columns and likewise Cars in a single column

I am currently using a convert record processor to convert from JSON to CSV, MY avro schema for both JSON and CSV looks like this
```

{
"name": "Sydney",
"type": "record",
"namespace": "sydney",
"fields": [
{
"name": "Bikes",
"type": {
"type": "array",
"items": {
"name": "Vehicle",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
{
"name": "Name",
"type": "string"
},
{
"name": "Model",
"type": "string"
},
{
"name": "Colour",
"type": "string"
}
]
}
}
},
{
"name": "Cars",
"type": {
"type": "array",
"items": {
"name": "Vehicle",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
{
"name": "Name",
"type": "string"
},
{
"name": "Model",
"type": "string"
},
{
"name": "Colour",
"type": "string"
}
]
}
}
}
]
}

```
but in the convert record processor I am getting this error
```

ConvertRecord[id=4d909c18-0177-1000-c1cd-9456a1775358] Failed to process StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=63d04fc1-7edd-405b-8a9d-000bcdaa3d6c,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1611930760172-32, container=default, section=32], offset=744686, length=4],offset=0,name=test.json,size=4]; will route to failure: IOException thrown from ConvertRecord[id=4d909c18-0177-1000-c1cd-9456a1775358]: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('T' (code 84)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: org.apache.nifi.stream.io.NonCloseableInputStream@5b8393b6; line: 1, column: 2]

```
Could anyone help me out on this?
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a jolt transform for this, which has its own processor. Restructuring a simple nested JSON like this is one of their documented examples.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is just an example and the problem I have is I want the entire Cars object as a single column in my CSV and the same for bikes so if i go for JOLT it will flatten the JSON and I will be having a single column for each fields.